# if statement problems in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have a method that checks for a null value from an editText on a click of a button like so:

```
public void myClickHandler09(View chv){
if (text9.equals("")){
    text9.setText("0");
}else{
    converter(text9);
}}
```

The

```
converter(text9);
```

method is as shown:

```
public void converter(View view){
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.Button09:
    RadioButton RadioButtons = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.RadioButton901);
    float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text9.getText().toString());


     if (RadioButtons.isChecked())  {
            text9.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertRadioButtons(inputValue)));
   }
       break;

}}

private double convertRadiobuttons(float inputValue){
    return inputValue * 6.4516;
}
```

The method is larger but here i've only called one radiobutton to shorten it.
Right now though the if statement seems to do absolutely nothing and so non of the rest of the code works. If i remove the method and rename

```
converter(View view){
```

to

```
myClickHandler09(View view){
```

then the code works and until you enter a null value into the EditText (then it crashes)

What am I doing wrong exactly here?

NOTE: the method name "myClickHandler09" is linked to the button as android:onClick in the xml

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I'm a little bit lost in the question but I figured I would mention in your `convert` method you are passing in the `View` but are using a different reference `text9.getText().toString()` it *might* be possible that `text9.getText()` is `null` and blowing up on the `toString()` call.. maybe not, but since you are passing in the reference directly why not use `((EditText)view).getText().toString()` because you already did the work of verifying that it wasn't `null`? Just caught my eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `if("".equals(text9.getText().toString())) { ...`

The `toString()` is there because the TextView will return a `CharSequence` which may or may not be a `String`.

Right now you are comparing the `TextView itself to ""`, and not the `String` it is showing.

**Edit** - As far as the crash goes, you also want to catch the `NumberFormatException` that [Float.parseFloat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29) throws.

```
float inputValue = 1.0f; // some default value, in case the user input is bad.
try {
    inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text9.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // possibly display a red flag next to the field
}
```

Comment: ::face palm:: cheers dude but the if statement is still taking no effect at all. Will it have something to do with the contents of the if and else or something to do with the structure of the method?

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint at the if statement? You can see the contents of the TextView at that point and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Ah, try doing text8.getText().toString()

Comment: sorry erm where can i put the exception catcher so that it doesn't show a duplicate variable error?

Comment: just replace your float inputValue ... line with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try

```
if ("".equals(text9.getText())) {

} else {

}
```

You essentially have to do a `getText()` from a `TextView` and not `equals` a String with a TextView.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't understand with your code is that you call:

converter(text9);

passing in the EditText, but by replacing converter(View  view) with the function name myClickHandler09 (like so):

myClickHandler09(View view) {

the button being pressed with call this function (if you defined it in the xml layout onClick paramter).

So to match this behaviour with your current code, try this out:

```
public void myClickHandler09(View btnView){
    if (text9.equals("")){
        text9.setText("0");
    } else {
        converter(btnView);
    }
}
```

I may have missed the point of you're post, but I think that is part of your issue. Also in stead of .equals("") I prefer (text9.toString().length() > 0) just seems a bit more logical, but that's me being a bit pedantic.